# Google wallet stripe integration in android

Tags: android, stripe-payments, android-pay

I am trying to integrate google wallet in my android app. I downloaded the sample app and modified it to work in my app but when I enter stripe test publishing key and stripe version the application gives me google unauthorized error code:404 error. Any idea why is this happening ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think Google Wallet is supported in Stripe just yet. Android Pay was announced recently but not released by Google just yet: https://stripe.com/android-pay

Comment: Keep in mind that your account's API version may need to be the latest once they launch as it would be an API feature most likely

Comment: Do stripe have that wallet facilities yet? @koopajah ?

Comment: https://stripe.com/docs/google-pay